# Can I Start particular program with different language settings in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, locale

I am using my windows with Turkish language as first choice. Non-Unicode programs also use Turkish language.

My particular program, Visual Studio 2005 (Business Intelligence Studio 2005) is behaving strangely with this language setting. It has no problems with English Language settings.

I would like to start only this program with English Language Settings.

I can use new bat/cmd file. Modify shortcut etc. Every solution is welcome. Only I do not want to change entire windows settings.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Create a new local user. (If the application you need in a different language needs administrator rights you should add the user to the local administrators group).
- Log in with that user and change the Windows language of that account to English.
- Log out
- Log in with your usual user.
- Run the application you want to see in a different language with the "Run As" method. (Shift+right click on the shortcut and select Run as different User)

You can create a batch with the RunAS command if you want ;-)

> %comspec% runas /profile /user:yourotheruser
> "the_application_you_want_ to_run_in_english"

Comment: WOW  you are awesome, @NetVivious

Comment: This works even if the binary has a digital signature (ex. Eclipse or OpenAdoptJDK). Note that the batch above doesn't work for Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if the application shows UAC before launching (ex. resmon.exe), you have to add the administrator privileges to the new local user. Otherwise, you cannot select the new local user in the UAC dialog, and the application will launch with the current user.

Comment: Added a little note to my answer using your tip. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4):

[Locale Emulator](https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator) works well on Windows 10 1809. I can run non-Unicode Simplified Chinese games on Windows with system locale set to Traditional Chinese with Locale Emulator!

Comment: LOL, The site identifies you as a new contributor, but it looks like you've been a member for 7 yrs.  Maybe first time posting?  Anyway, the question is specifically about Win 7.  It's useful to provide updated information, but do you happen to know if this also works for Win 7?  It would also be good to include relevant information like the fact that this isn't ready to use out-of-the-box, and also requires other software.  BTW, good guidance on recommending software here: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.

Comment: Thanks for your notification. However, I think my answer for Win 10 still has meanings for this question, because this question title doesn't limit the Windows version. People, like me, could search to this question for an answer for Win 10 by search engine. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, no issue with the fact that it's known to work in Win 10, that can be valuable for current readers.  I was mainly referring to additional information that would make it a better answer.  :-)

Comment: This answer is informative, but Locale Emulator doesn't work for the binary with a digital signature (ex. Eclipse or OpenAdoptJDK).

Comment: Not works on 64bit apps

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest trying Microsoft's [AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13209).

It allows you to start a program using a different language.

Please note that because you are using Windows 7, you have to install it using an elevated command prompt. Instructions for installing AppLocale in Windows 7 can be found [here](http://www.pressbyte.com/1924/download-install-microsoft-applocale-windows-7/).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried but did not work for me.

Comment: None of the links work any longer, so this is a useless answer.

Comment: The links say: "We're sorry, this download is no longer available." and "Error establishing a database connection"

Comment: For Windows 10, the Locale Emulator worked: https://superuser.com/a/1384964/128124