# Make Language change specific to window/app not whole system (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, keyboard, windows-8.1, language

I have Windows 8.1 Pro English. Sometime I need to use another languages (I did not install any language packs and my locale is English). So I have a few keyboards enabled. However in W7 when I switch keyboard it stays in the window I switched it.. and other windows have English at the same time... In windows 8.1 if I switch keyboard it changes everywhere.

is there an option to keep different keyboards in different windows / apps ?

Comment: Windoes does not support this.  Infact the language choice of Windows is only Microsoft products built-into Windows itself.  All language support is support by programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Start particular program with different language settings in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/384775/can-i-start-particular-program-with-different-language-settings-in-windows)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Control Panel - Language - Advanced Settings - Let me set a different input for each app window

Comment: Which version of windows does it have to be? There is no such an option in windows 7, if I'm not missing anything

Comment: @Nexen did you find the setting? I couldnot find it out :(

Comment: @Luke unfortunately no luck here

Answer (score 37):

Noticing there's no reply re. Windows 10 (which was my problem and the reason I reached this forum), here are the setting to make language input application-specific in Windows 10:

Start > Settings > Time & Language > Region & language > Additional date, time & regional settings > (under Language) Change input methods > Advanced settings > (under switching input methods) Let me set a different input method for each app window

Good job Microsoft, I don't think you could have hid this any better :p

Comment: The shorter address in windows 10 to access that option is from `Control Panel` : `Clock, Language, and Region \ Language \ Advanced settings` , Let me set a different input method for each app window

Comment: I agree - things getting somewhat confusing with each iteration with MS. But its the public which made them do it - mediocre "developers" pushed them off the rigorous software building to an "agile" do any kind of crap you want and quick and move on.. Re: language.. you can press Windows button and start typing "let me set.." and you get your setting ;) P.S. just saw the other answers - the already had it :)

Answer (score 17):

In my Windows 10, I do not have the Change input methods, so here is another flavor to make Windows remember the language input.

Start > Settings > Time & Language > Region & language > Advanced keyboard settings > Let me use a different input method for each app window.

[image]

You can simply type "advanced keyboard settings" in the start menu to reach it instantly.

Answer (score 7):

And yet again, new path for latest **Windows 10 build 1809**:

Start > Settings > Time & Language > Language > Spelling, typings, & keyboard settings > Advanced keyboard settings > Let me use a different input method for each app window

or

Start > Settings > type into search: "Let me use"

Answer (score 2):

A more simple and reliable way on Windows 10, press `win` key, then input `Advanced keyboard settings`, it will be shown at the top of `Best match` group, then click it and select "Let me use ..."

Answer (score 1):

In win10 Settings->Time & Language -> Region & Language -> Advance Keyboard Settings 
Under 'Switching input method' select "let me use a different input method for each app window"