# How to launch a 64-bit program with a different locale than the system locale?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, 64-bit, locale

I'm looking for a way to launch 64-bit programs in a Chinese, Japanese, and Russian locale without changing my current system locale (which is English). With Microsoft's AppLocale I was able to launch 32-bit programs in any locale but AppLocale doesn't launch 64-bit programs in a locale different to the system locale.

I currently use Windows 8.1 x64

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's more easy:
This method works for all Windows 32bits or 64bits ;-)

- Create different new local users (one for each language).
- Log in with each user and change the Windows language of that account to the desired language.
- Log out
  (Repeat for each user).

When you finish the setup:

- Log in with your usual user.
- Run the application you want to see in a different language with the
  "Run As" method (Shift+right click on the shortcut and select Run as
  different User) using the user which has that language on his
  settings.

Comment: It works but that means that I have to create at least 3 extra accounts on my PC that I will never use

Comment: Yes I know. But until Microsoft don't updates the AppLocale application it's the only solution I found.

Comment: Where's the "Run as a different user" option?  In the Start Menu, it's shown when right you click the program, and in Explorer if you Shift+Right click the executable.  (You've mentioned this your [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/922770) but not this one.)

Comment: Changed, thx ;-)

Answer (score 8):

There's an open-source alternative to Microsoft AppLocale that is claimed to work up to windows 10, available on GitHub:

https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator

Its allows per-app locale settings, accessible via a context menu option.

Comment: The official site for Locale Emulator http://xupefei.github.io/Locale-Emulator/ says It works on 64-bit OS but not on 64-bit programs. So it's the same problem as with AppLocale

Comment: There's [Locale Remulator](https://github.com/InWILL/Locale_Remulator) now.