# Start an application with specific date format

Tags: windows-10, runas, psexec, regional-settings

I need to use one rather poorly-coded application which requires me to use en-US regional settings, or more specifically, the date format needs to be in en-US format when executing that application. I don't want to use en-US date format when I regularly use my PC. I'd like to start this application using just a double-click, without changing the regional settings manually when using it.

**I have created a special user as a member of "Administrators" group (this program requires elevation) and set its regional settings to en-US, with the idea to use `runas` to launch this application using the different user credentials, hoping that if I launched the app this way, it would pick up the given user regional setting.**

I have also tried doing this using PsExec from SysInternals Suite.

However, the application still uses my regional settings. My OS is Windows 10 64-bit. Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: The accepted answer of the linked (possible duplicate) question is the same as what I've already tried (and marked with bold now for clarity).

EDIT2: The application I am trying to launch is 32-bit, but requires elevation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch a 64-bit program with a different locale than the system locale?](https://superuser.com/questions/905522/how-to-launch-a-64-bit-program-with-a-different-locale-than-the-system-locale)

Comment: @user have you read what I have tried?

Comment: Lose the attitude.  Did you try the suggested alternative to Microsoft AppLocale?  Before you respond to my comment, in any fashion, please note you made no mention if this was a 32-bit or 64-bit application.  If you are rude to me, I will report the comment, and won't even respond.  Honestly, I would remove the hostility from your question, because it's extremely hostile towards the community and is not required.  Your OS is 64-bit but that does not tell me if the application is 64-bit or not and it makes a difference.

Comment: Worth pointing out that, if the application is 32-bit, and Locale-Emulator doesn't solve your problem, then it is very possible the application simply wasn't designed to run under a different locale (and thus the application would have to be fixed) to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your attention. I have edited the question with additional information. I have also tried with the Locale Emulator and it doesn't work. This Locale Emulator probably overrides the thread UI culture, however I need something to override the thread culture itself. Unfortunately I don't have access to the application source code so can't fix it.

Comment: “This Locale Emulator probably overrides the thread UI culture, however I need something to override the thread culture itself.“ -What? Your analysis is incorrect

Comment: I said probably - maybe I'm wrong. The fact is that it didn't help... But there, I solved the problem and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this particular problem using a simple, quick and dirty way. As all this application requires is changing the date format (more specifically, short date format) I have created an application which:

1. saves the current date format from Registry (from HKCU\Control Panel\International)
2. changes the date format to the one required by the application I'm launching
3. launches the application
4. waits for the application to load
5. changes the date format setting value back to the previous value

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RF_vu_-5Qk_ytE93iRzfK0zJGi5706ey

[Source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RF_vu_-5Qk_ytE93iRzfK0zJGi5706ey)

Requires .NET Framework 4.6.
Contains appSettings.json which lets you change the application to launch, parameters and the date format to set.