# Is it possible (how to) run an app in Windows with certain keyboard language preset?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

So, I have set my keyboard language setting as "per app" (not global as Win 10 default) and I use some apps only with English layout, but when I run them, they always start with Russian keyboard layout. Is it possible to run an app with English layout preset (say, `cmd`)? Ideally, I'd like to change my .lnk files in some fashion like

```
C:\some path\anApp.exe
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe --keyboard-language en-us
C:\some path\anotherApp.exe --keyboard-language ru
```

so that they launch the app in that way; but cmd or AutoHotKey scripts are also acceptable.

Comment: If [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1262073/per-app-input-language-windows-10) gets an answer that would be sufficient

Comment: Although [here](https://superuser.com/q/384775/576393) is no accepted answer, my question actually duplicates it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator deserves a try, the claimed functionality seems to be exactly what I need

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but there is this.
*Settings -> Time & Language -> Region & Language -> Additional Date, Time & Language Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Switching Input Settings*. They couldn't have hidden it any better!!!

Comment: yeap, I was there, but there's no hint about how to set a per-app on-open layout, only a setting to allow per-app layout

Comment: It probably has to be done programmatically although my forte is C & Python whereas you'll probably need to write C# for this, there might be a PowerShell cmdlet

Comment: hmm, according to [this article](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-set-language-on-a-per-app-basis-in-windows-10/) the chosen languages should be saved on per-app basis so once one reopens them, they should get restored.. which is not the case for me! (for instance, for cmd) Either the article is wrong or this is a bug

Comment: No such settings on my win 10 system.